# The meaning of「無理のない予定で構いません。」

Tags: meaning

My Japanese is dubious at best. Online translator tools is saving me most of the time. But I'll provide some context at least: In a project with our Japanese business partner we have been running a little bit late in most steps so far. And I've just provided an estimate (time and price) for the next step. After thanking me for the estimate he follows up with this:

> こちらの着手から実装はおおよそどのくらいの期間が必要でしょうか？
>    無理のない予定で構いません。

When we can start, which is obvious I guess, but that last bit makes me scratch my head. Is it perhaps a hint that we are requesting too little time (yet again), or since it comes directly after the question is it just a "There is no need to rush." kind of thing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it perhaps a hint that we are requesting too little time (yet again), or since it comes directly after the question is it just a "There is no need to rush." kind of thing?

The latter.

> 「無理{むり}のない予定{よてい}で構{かま}いません。」

means:

> "We will be happy with a realistic and no-stress (on your part) kind of plan."

That is obviously not a literal translation, but it is what it means.

Comment: I'm just curious, is the で in 無理のない予定で構いません functioning as the conjunctive form of だ/です or is it functioning as a particle (perhaps explaining circumstance)?

Comment: @G-Cam I think it's a particle で ("with").

Answer (score 0):

こちらの着手から実装はおおよそどのくらいの期間が必要でしょうか？ 無理のない予定で構いません。
"Once work begins on the project about how long will it take? (Just) an approximate estimate is fine."

I think it reinforces the first sentence. The sense I get is that they don't need a formal schedule but something to use as a base for planning.